# Spring MVC, subfolder in form action

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, action

I have problem, how to create uri in action attribute. I have to use subfolders as "user", "admin" because I use Spring Security.

```
<form:form action="/user/reservationTour.html" method="post" commandName="bookTourForm">
```

Result, no project name http://localhost:8080/user/reservationTour.html

```
<form:form action="user/reservationTour.html" method="post" commandName="bookTourForm">
```

Result, 2x user in link http://localhost:8080/ProjectContextTitle/user/user/reservationTour.html

```
<form:form action="<c:url value="/user/reservationTour.html" />" method="post" commandName="bookTourForm">
```

Result, exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/user/reservationTourPage.jsp(7,33) Unterminated &lt;form:form tag
```

This works fine, but sure not good solution

```
<form:form action="/ProjectContextName/user/reservationTour.html" method="post" commandName="bookTourForm">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're already in the user directory, you just need to use a relative URL:

```
<form:form action="reservationTour.html" method="post" commandName="bookTourForm">
```

If you want to use an absolute URL, use `<c:url>`, but don't include it in the attribute of another JSP tag: that's illegal.

```
<c:url value="/user/reservationTour.html" var="theAction"/>
<form:form action="${theAction}" ...>
```

Comment: Your second attempt in your question shows that the form is in a page that has an URL uner the `/YourApp/user` path. That's why, when the relative URL of your action is `user/reservationTour.html`, you end up with `/YourApp/user/user/reservationTour.html`. So if the relative URL is just `reservationTour.html`, it will obviously end up with `/YourApp/user/reservationTour.html`, which is what you want.