# using Spring jstl and spring form tags together

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jstl

Is it possible to mix jstl and spring form tags in a jsp page in a spring mvc application?

```
<form:form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>">
    code
</form:form>
```

The output is:

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>">
    code
</form>
```

The spring tags are getting parse but the jstl tags are not getting parse. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the output that you are seeing??

Comment: Did you add jstl core tag in your jsp?

Comment: Please post the error stacktrace

Comment: There is not stacktrace. The action attribute's value isn't getting parsed as intended. @Octopus

Comment: @nick-s Did you try my answer? Please let me know what happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the accepted answer, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334623/spring-mvc-subfolder-in-form-action). we shouldn't mix up c:url tag with spring form tags, that is illegal. You have to instead do it this way

```
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="theAction"/>
<form:form method="POST" action="${theAction}">
code
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add taglib in your jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Hope you added only the below spring-form taglib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```